# Google Analytics: Data is configured for Ecommerce, but no data is flowing

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

I am unable to get any ecommerce data to show on GA no matter what I try. I have the script from the settings section of the GA Dashboard implemented correctly on my site and I am getting page views but no Ecommerce data is being sent. I have tried using GA Debugger but not sure what I am looking for.

I get the error "View xxxxx is configured for Ecommerce, but no data is flowing."

The way the checkout works is a JS popup window manages all adding to cart, entering details, payments etc... including the completion page which is all managed in this popup.

The options for Ecommerce Tracking are turned on both in GA and my third party cart so I don't understand why I can not see any data. Any ideas?

Here is the GA Debugger info I get but again, I don't know what I am looking for.

```
Initializing Google Analytics.
    Running command: ga("create", "UA-50046647-1", {cookieDomain: "auto", name: "gtag_UA_50046647_1"})
        Creating new tracker: gtag_UA_50046647_1
        Auto cookieDomain found: "ryankerswell.co.uk"
    Running command: ga(Function)
    Running command: ga("gtag_UA_50046647_1.send", "pageview", {forceSSL: true, &gtm: "u46", hitCallback: [function]})
        Setting throttling cookie: "_gat_gtag_UA_50046647_1"

        Sent beacon:
        v=1&_v=j67d&a=222021260&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ryankerswell.co.uk%2Fshop%2Ftest-gallery&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&sd=24-bit&sr=1680x1050&vp=966x862&je=0&_utma=202048402.732414250.1516658797.1519416183.1523226553.3&_utmz=202048402.1517163055.1.1.utmcsr%3D(direct)%7Cutmccn%3D(direct)%7Cutmcmd%3D(none)&_utmht=1524343674796&_u=AACCAUAB~&jid=398813576&gjid=367406371&cid=732414250.1516658797&tid=UA-50046647-1&_gid=794852234.1524340782&_r=1&gtm=u46&z=521904556

        <unknown>        (&gtm)  u46
        _j1              (&jid)  398813576
        _j2              (&gjid) 367406371
        adSenseId        (&a)    222021260
        apiVersion       (&v)    1
        clientId         (&cid)  732414250.1516658797
        encoding         (&de)   UTF-8
        hitType          (&t)    pageview
        javaEnabled      (&je)   0
        language         (&ul)   en-us
        location         (&dl)   https://www.ryankerswell.co.uk/shop/test-gallery
        screenColors     (&sd)   24-bit
        screenResolution (&sr)   1680x1050
        trackingId       (&tid)  UA-50046647-1
        viewportSize     (&vp)   966x862

    Registered new plugin: ga(provide, "render", Function)
```

Comment: Can you share the debug console output at the point where the transaction is confirmed?

Comment: Nothing changes what you see above is all that is displayed. Only difference is the third party plugin adds its own tracking code so it can monitor the transaction. This is what is added during and after the transaction. `Snipcart:  Adding item 4359 to cart dde38fe8-c051-4f54-a186-e0db3ec76cda.  Succesfully added item 4359 to cart dde38fe8-c051-4f54-a186-e0db3ec76cda.`

Comment: If there is no change then it indicates that the Enhanced E-commerce code is not being fired. It would be useful to see how you have implemented the code in order to troubleshoot it